# Question words What for? and For what?

Tags: questions

It seems "What for?" is BrE. And "For what?" AmE. But it may be that both
expressions are interchangeable in BrE and AmE.

Comment: Both are used in AmE.

Answer (score 5):

So what is your question? :)

I wouldn't say one is BrE and one is AmE.  Usage depends on the context.

> "Please jump up and down three times".
>
> "What for?"

That could easily be heard in either country.

> "I am going to make you pay".
>
> "For what?"

Would also be common in both places.

You might occasionally use "What for?" in the second example, but I wouldn't expect anyone to say "For what?" in reponse to the first question. Either in Britain or America.

Comment: And if you used _What for?_ in the second example, it would mean something else: _For what?_ would mean _Pay for what?_, and _What for?_ would more probably mean _Why would you do that?_.

Comment: "What for?" in the second case could mean either depending on your tone and how you emphasized the word "for".  "What for?" could mean "why?", "What *for*?" would mean the same as "For what?"